# Xdebug do netbeans não funciona

Tags: netbeans, debug

Estou tentando usando o Xdebug do Netbeans. Faço a marcação da linha, e depois clico em "Depurar arquivo". No entanto, não me acontece nada! Tem alguma configuração especifica que devo fazer? Quando faço esse procedimento, no canto direito do Netbeans fica "Aguardando conexão (netbeans-xdebug)".

Comment: Xdebug do php? Ele está habilitado no servidor?

Comment: No php.ini? Se for, qual a linha que habilito?

Comment: procure essa linha no php.ini: `[XDebug] zend_extension = caminho da extensão.` e remova o ponto e virgula dela, reinicie o apache, agora as msg de erro devem aparecer em laranjado isso significa queo xdebug foi habilite corretamente.

Comment: `zend_extension = "D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"` . Está dessa forma, acho que está tudo certo! E mesmo assim não funcionou!

Answer (score 2):

Andraw, sou iniciante em [php](/questions/tagged/php) e passei pelo mesmo problema, pesquisei, pesquisei, e deu consegui!

Para verificar certinho o caminho para colocar a dll do xdebug, utilize o próprio site do xdebug, onde tem uma parte de [Instruções de instalação](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php)*, te fornecera o caminho correto, como disse o @rray devera começar aparecer os erros em laranjado.

**php.ini**
(no meu php.ini não tinha nada referente a XDebug)

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
```

O caminho foi o que o site com as instruções me gerou:

> You're already running the latest Xdebug version
>
> But here are the instructions anyway:
>
> 1. Download php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11.dll
> 2. Move the downloaded file to C:\xampp\php\ext
> 3. Update `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and change the line
>      `zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11.dll`
> 4. Restart the webserver

*Cole na caixa de texto do site, a saída de `phpinfo()` (pode ser o codigo fonte da pagina HTML gerada, ou a saída do `php -i`)

Qualquer dúvida pode perguntar, fiquei tentando resolver isso pode ter faltado alguma coisa :)

Answer (score 0):

adicione a seguinte seção no seu php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension_ts = "./php/ext/php_xdebug<version>.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="<XAMPP_HOME>\tmp"
```

Fonte: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html